# How to fix 'The command "npm install" exited with code 1' error when building the ASP.NET Core app with React?

Tags: asp.net, reactjs

I am new to ReactJS. I am trying to build the default application created using  ASP.NET Core and React.

[image: Selector image]

I am getting build error.

> error MSB3073: The command "npm install" exited with code 1.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: If you go to View → Output, what does it say in there?

Answer (score 15):

Running Visual Studio as administrator worked for me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't have `node & npm` globally installed.

You can use a script like https://github.com/creationix/nvm that helps you manage different versions of nodejs

Or you can just install it straight from https://nodejs.org/en/